# How do I get Clear Wireless to work on Ubuntu? Is there a solution?

Tags: wireless

I have seen quite a few posts on this issue but no solutions I could find. Does anyone know of a way to get a connection using Clear. I really don't want to give up using ubuntu but it seems like I have to. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a proud user of Archlinux, I'm able to connect via Clear's USB WiMAX devices.
I believe this should work on Ubuntu as well though!

So try the following:

Make sure the correct module(s) are loaded for the OS to recognize the USB device.   (In my case, I only need the usbnet module)

```
sudo modprobe usbnet 
sudo modprobe rndis_host
```

Check if the device is being recognized by your system

```
ifconfig -a
```

Bring up the USB network device and request a dynamic IP for system with net-tools package.

```
sudo ifconfig usb0 up && sudo dhcpcd usb0
```

Or use this command if you use the newer ip-tools package.

```
sudo ip link set usb0 up && sudo dhcpcd usb0
```

Change settings on WiMAX USB device by navigating to your WiMAX configuration page in a web browser.

- Browse to the IP which DHCP you were able to get a lease on: (most likely, `http://192.168.14.1`)
- Go to Advanced and change setting to NAT and stick with default values
- Save Changes

Restart DHCP

```
sudo dhcpcd -x  && sudo dhcpcd usb0
```

Hopefully at this point you DHCP request will come back with another address, such as `http://192.168.14.1`

That's it.  Now go play on YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, nobody has been able to get the Clear USB sticks to work with Linux yet.

To do this, you will want to use a "[Clear Hub](http://www.clear.com/devices/hubs)." These devices use standard Ethernet and Wi-Fi connections and so are not dependent on Windows.

Comment: I have also heard about porting in wifi through a virtual maching running windows in ubuntu. Has anyone tried this and what were the methods or drawbacks?